# How to click an item in a grid of images and return the selected image in a different container - Javascript

Tags: javascript, image, onclick

The large_image should appear as any of the grid_images that is clicked by the user. 
I've searched S.O.F. and google, but have not found a solution to this problem.

```
<div id="large_image" class="container">
    <img src="">
</div>
<div id="grid_images" class="container">
    <img src="assets/images/rock.png">
    <img src="assets/images/paper.png">
    <img src="assets/images/scissors.png">
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
function change_image {
    document.getElementById("large_image").img = 
    // How do I select the image that is clicked?
}
```

Comment: How are you currently calling `change_image`? Is it bound as a listener for the `click` event on the images inside `grid_images`?

Comment: @Elezar I was going to add "onClick=change_image();" to each img element in grid_images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, a few things. First, in order to update the `src` of the `img` under `large_image`, you need a way to reference that `img` element. The easiest way to do that is to give the `img` element an ID. Since you're not using the ID on its parent div, I'm going to move that to the `img`. If you do need the ID on the div, then just make sure that the ID on the `img` is unique.

Now, when you call change_image, you'll need to pass in the source of the img that was clicked on, so you can set that to the source of the large_image. Here's what your JavaScript function should look like:

```
function change_image(imgSrc) {
    document.getElementById("large_image").src = imgSrc;
}
```

And here's what the HTML should look like:

```
<div class="container">
    <img id="large_image" src="">
</div>
<div id="grid_images" class="container">
    <img src="assets/images/rock.png" onclick="change_image(this.src);">
    <img src="assets/images/paper.png" onclick="change_image(this.src);">
    <img src="assets/images/scissors.png" onclick="change_image(this.src);">
</div>
```

The snippet below shows it in action, using different sources for the images, of course.

```js
    function change_image(imgSrc) {
      document.getElementById("large_image").src = imgSrc;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img id="large_image" src="">
</div>
<div id="grid_images" class="container">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c8/Aerial_Crater_Lake.jpg/320px-Aerial_Crater_Lake.jpg" onclick="change_image(this.src);">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6f/Boating_in_Spirit_Lake-pre_1980.jpg" onclick="change_image(this.src);">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/1/1e/Okanagan_Lake.jpg/320px-Okanagan_Lake.jpg" onclick="change_image(this.src);">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use jQuery, enclose the following code inside $(document).ready(function(){ ... })  otherwise add it to the bottom of the page.

```
  var largeImage = document.getElementById("large_image");
  var gridImage = document.getElementById("grid_images");

  gridImage.addEventListener('click', function(event) { 
      largeImage.removeChild(largeImage.firstChild);
      largeImage.appendChild(event.target.cloneNode());
  });
```